# save the content of a text area to a FileField in Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, filefield

I'm stuck lately on a weird problem with my django project, and I wanted to share this with you. well, in my project, I want to give the user the possibility to update the content of textfiles which he has upload earlier, and to do so, I considered copying the content of the file to a textarea, where the modification will take place, and after submitting the modification, update the file. In fact, I found this solution here in this forum, it's saving the updates but to another path ! Here's the solution suggested :

views.py:

```
 def update_file(request, id):
    file = UploadedFile.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
       from django.core.files import File
       f = open(file.docfile.path,'w+b')
       content = request.POST['content']
       f.write(content)
       file.docfile = File(f)
       file.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    else:
       docfile = file.docfile.read()
       return render_to_response('update_file.html',{'file':file,  'docfile' :
                   docfile}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

update_file.html:

```
<form action="/update_file/{{file.id}}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
{% csrf_token %}
    <p><textarea name="content">
        {{docfile}}
    </textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer"/></p>
</form>
```

when I run this code, I prints the text on the screen, update it normally, and save it back to the database, but in a different path, for instance, the path containing the files is : "media/documents/username/", but after modifying the file, it will be saved under the directory : "documents/username//home/Ubuntu-user/file_sharing_project/file_sharing_project/media/documents/username/" et hence the path changes in a recursive way ! Any clues about this problem, and for the record, I'm only a beginner in django and python in general!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/ 
It says that its not going to replace a file instead going to create a new one.

So you can take approaches here, 
Destroy the old file one you can a new one.

Or else just have all the them saved, user might also want to see a older version at some point of time.

And also you might want to considering closing file after your done with it.

Comment: ah, i see ! so you're saying that if i destroy the old version of the file before saving the new one, there won't be the change path mentioned above ?!

Comment: Essentially your removing the old one and creating a new one, so path should not  be a problem

Comment: ok, thanks for the good response, it really helped me to know the origin of the problem ! it's in the save the method ! each time the upload_path function gives a new path, more and more complicated ! anyway, it's not a blocking problem but it still bothers me, I'll try to find a work around !